# Backup powershell script pauses until i press space

Tags: exchange, powershell, scripting

I made a script to export all mailboxes ( as secondary backup for my Exchange 2013 Server.)

The script basically gets all the mailboxes from a list in a text file and does a for-loop going through each user's mailbox and exporting it to a pst. Inside that loop i have a while condition that waits for the backup to finish before continuing to the next mailbox.

Well, the script works fine, until after a while (specially on big mailboxes) the script pauses for whatever reason, and so in order to make it go again i have to go in to the powershell window and press space or enter in order for the script to continue...

```
SCREEN OUTPUT example: 

Starting <USER> PST EXPORT.. //after 60 seconds the next line comes in
Export is still in progress.. Checking again in 1 minute.
Backup Successful
Starting <USER> PST EXPORT..
```

At some point the script seems to pause or get stuck and i would have to go and press space or enter. It does this randomly, but specially on users with big mailboxes.

So I'm wondering, is there a script run time limit? or why would it do that?

Comment: Please share us with the script.

Comment: "is there a script run time limit?" No. "why would it do that?" Does the titlebar of the PowerShell console happen to list "Select" in it when it is stuck?

Comment: In your powershell console, is **Quick Edit** enabled?  Is it getting stuck because you are going into 'edit' mode?

Answer (score 0):

What does this "secondary backup" do other than waste disk space? 
Brick level backups have been a complete waste of time, space and energy for many years. With a combination of a proper backup using an Exchange aware backup and deleted item retention their usefulness is zero.

They cannot be used for server recovery, item level recovery I can do with the above combination. If you need to keep a record of the mailboxes at a certain point in time, just ensure that you have a proper procedure for doing so.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Sometimes a question is misguided and the answer is "don't do that" or "that is not good practice, do this instead".